# Service deployed on EKS does not answer on its EXTERNAL-IP

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-elb, amazon-eks

1. I created a small application, made a docker image of it, which runs
   fine locally using docker run.
2. I created an EKS cluster on amazon.
3. I put the image up on ECR, wrote a yaml file for a deployment and loadbalancer service, and used kubectl apply -f to deploy to my cluster

I can see my service:

```
$ kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP                                                               PORT(S)        AGE
frd-front    LoadBalancer   10.100.199.8   a2c269b1619ee11ea90f20636eb75c46-1160809648.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com   80:32594/TCP   40m
kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.100.0.1     <none>                                                                    443/TCP        22h
```

But if I go to http://a2c269b1619ee11ea90f20636eb75c46-1160809648.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com there is no repsponse

- How can I start troubleshooting this?
- Do you have any ideas right off the bat?

Thanks  =)

Comment: Can you access your app from inside the cluster?

Comment: @KFC_ I can access my app by using kubectl port-forward as Umesh mentioned. So I know the app responds, I know the service responds. I'm wondering if the trouble is that I set my service to listen on port 80, often blocked by default. Do I need another step to open port 80 on my cluster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue can be one of the two  reasons:

1. **Docker image**: the image may not be exposing the output as expected on the mentioned port.
2. **K8s Service**: the service YAML may be configured with wrong target port or service port

if you find that there is no issue in both the reasons.

Try to use port-forward on your pod  and check weather is  available.

Usage: 
check for pod

```
kubectl port-forward pod-name-765d459796-258hz 8080:8080 // host-port:container-port
```

check for service

```
kubectl port-forward svc/myservice 80:8080
```

- If both are working fine, then its issue with loadbalancer side or service outbound or network policies.
- If not working even after port-forward then issue with docker image or deployment yaml.

Comment: Thanks that does help. Got me: Unable to listen on port 80: Listeners failed to create with the following errors: [unable to create listener: Error listen tcp4 127.0.0.1:80: bind: permission denied unable to create listener: Error listen tcp6 [::1]:80: bind: permission denied]
error: unable to listen on any of the requested ports: [{80 8080}]

Also my deployment pod is KO, ErrImageNeverPull -- going to search what that means

Comment: @swafran Maybe the image URL or tag is not proper.  Also, do approve if that answers your question.

Comment: Tag and image are ok. I can reach the service with port-forward. I am marking your answer correct, as I asked for troubleshooting steps and you gave good ones that helped me. Now that I know the service responds, but something is wrong in network or outbound, where do I go to check that?

Comment: Maybe any kind of network policy is blocking the traffic.. check ```kubectl get networkpolicies --all-namespaces``` . Or do you use istio on the cluster?